# Login form does not store/remember/suggest users password

Tags: login, password, wp-login-form

I'm struggling (very much struggling) to find a fix for my issue. I'm using WP 5.4.1 with PointFinder theme. The problem is that even if the 'remember me' checkbox is turned on, users have to fill the password field all the time. I was looking for solutions similar to my case and I didn't find any suitable. I also did not take any action because I'm not so confident with it, despite the fact to try with plugins like "always remember me" or similars that didn't work. My site is www.appets.it

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance, Marco.

Comment: Check the expiration times of the login cookies that your site is generating, both the timestamp in the cookie (the second block) and the lifetime of the cookie itself.

Comment: Hello Rup, thanks for the advice! I see different cookies for my website and I'm not sure which one is the "login" cookie. Anyway, I found that for some of them the expiration is when the session expires. Others 1 year, 1 month, there are many kind of them, even 88 years.